# Cross browser page display

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have my code http://snipt.org/umnnh/ there. With all my browsers, it lines up fine, except with Mozilla Firefox. With Mozilla Firefox it will get messed up (the text box will be too wide, and too high). Is there an easy fix for this? I am pretty much clueless on what is wrong.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a link to a screenshot of the problem you're having?

Comment: Partly off topic: Never ever use tables for design purposes ... big no no!

Answer (score 1):

Your image is outside the table with login fields so they get in different places. Try putting the image as a background of the table tag:

```
<table style="background-image:url('http://www.trinuxsoft.info/os/images/loginform.png')" width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
```

Or you could use a div with the image as the background image and the table inside.

I suggest you Firebug Firefox plugin, it's great when you want to understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a `<!DOCTYPE>` tag so I presume your toolset does not include an HTML validator. If you add a DOCTYPE (e.g. 4.0 transitional) and [validate the code](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) you'll see there're some errors. The main problem with invalid HTML is that you make the browser guess. While proper rendering is basically identical in all browsers (at leas in theory), quirks mode is an unpredictable collection of per-browser tricks.

It's also worth noting that using `width` attributes in table cells is not a good way to get a layout. It's not reliable because HTML dictates some complicate rules to display tables and your custom sizes are likely to be ignored. You should either let the browser choose all sizes or switch to CSS layouts.